# how can read a QR code in arm based handheld terminals

Tags: qr-code, handheld

now we are in research of qr code so how can read a QR code in arm based handheld terminals using c++ or C#

thanks in advance.

Comment: Did your research effort include the rudimentary use of Google?  In general, we expect to see some code (and prior effort) in questions on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[zxing](https://code.google.com/p/zxing/) has an actively maintained C++ decoder (FWIW, I'm the primary maintainer of the C++ port.)

Answer (score 0):

By using a library. I haven't used it, but the first Google hit suggests that [libqr](http://www.norisys.jp/libqr/) is well-known. Written in C89, which you should be able to use.

Comment: libqr doesn't decode ("It currently supports generation; parsing and discovery modules are planned.")